# Looking for a more efficient way to write this jquery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to Jquery, so I've been going through some examples on w3schools.com, to get some ideas how to write better code. Out of more curiosity than anything, I came up with this pretty simple menu, which has four divs, a main div called `#main-slide` which contains three links that points to three sub slides `sub-slide-one`, `sub-slide-two`, `sub-slide-three`. By the way none of these actually slide in or out I just for whatever reason named them that way.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>


  <div id="main-slide">

    <a class="Subone" href="#">SUB ONE</a>
    <a class="Subtwo" href="#">SUB TWO</a>
    <a class="Subthree" href="#">SUB THREE</a>

  </div>


  <div id="sub-slide-one">

    <h1>SUB ONE</h1>

    <a class="BackMain1" href="#">BACK TO MAIN</a>

  </div>

  <div id="sub-slide-two">

    <h1>SUB TWO</h1>

    <a class="BackMain2" href="#">BACK TO MAIN</a>

  </div>



  <div id="sub-slide-three">

    <h1>SUB THREE</h1>

    <a class="BackMain3" href="#">BACK TO MAIN</a>

  </div>

</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#sub-slide-one,
#sub-slide-two,
#sub-slide-three {
  display: none;
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#main-slide {
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  display: block;
}

#sub-slide-one {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

#sub-slide-two {
  background-color: crimson;
}

#sub-slide-three {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.Subone,
.Subtwo,
.Subthree {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.Subone {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.Subtwo {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}

.Subthree {
  background-color: darkgoldenrod
}
```

For the JavaScript each link has a fadein/fadeout click function on it. For example when `Subone` is clicked the `#main-slide` is faded out and `sub-slide-one` is faded in. Each sub slide contain a back link which links back to the main slide. This is where I ultimately run into problems, the menu works as intended, although when I click the `SubThree` link it jumps to the top first for whatever reason.

But to get the back links to fadein/out the divs properly I had to create each back link with a separate class, and separate function to get the desired result.

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".Subone").click(function() {
    $("#main-slide").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#sub-slide-one").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);

  });

  $(".Subtwo").click(function() {
    $("#main-slide").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#sub-slide-two").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);

  });

  $(".Subthree").click(function() {
    $("#main-slide").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#sub-slide-three").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);

  });


  $(".BackMain1").click(function() {
    $("#sub-slide-one").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#main-slide").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);

  });

  $(".BackMain2").click(function() {
    $("#sub-slide-two").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#main-slide").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);

  });

  $(".BackMain3").click(function() {
    $("#sub-slide-three").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#main-slide").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);

  });


});
```

I have to believe there is a much more efficient way to do this, but I can't seem to figure out how. Here's a link to JSfiddle to see this in action https://jsfiddle.net/Dylancougar/k9f53wpp/

Comment: Please use inline code formattin rather tham bold formatting for variables and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a common class for parent menu and also an ID to use it as a relation between parent and children menu. Get the ID on Click and use it to decide which submenu has to react :

```
 <div id="main-slide">

    <a class="topmenu" id="1" href="#">SUB ONE</a>
    <a class="topmenu" id="2" href="#">SUB TWO</a>
    <a class="topmenu" id="3" href="#">SUB THREE</a>

  </div>


  <div id="sub-slide-1">

    <h1>SUB ONE</h1>

    <a class="Back" id="1" href="#">BACK TO MAIN</a>

  </div>
```

jquery:

```
  $(".topmenu").click(function() {
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    $("#main-slide").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#sub-slide-"+id).delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);
  });
```

and use same method for closing the proper submenu.

```
  $(".back").click(function() {
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    $("#sub-slide-"+id).fadeOut(1200);
    $("#main-slide").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);
  });
```

Please consider that repeating and ID within a single page is not suggested. So you can define more complex IDs e.g. open1 or close1 and remove the extra words before calculations.

`var id=$(this).attr("id").replace("open","");`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/TyrionGraphiste/zmL5bgwt/).
So you will have to change your HTML structure by adding a common class for every same elements and add an id for each of them. It will change your CSS a bit.

JS

```
$(function () {
  $(".sub").on('click', function (e) {
    let number = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];

    $("#main-slide").fadeOut(1200);
    $("#sub-slide-" + number).delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);

    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(".backMain").on('click', function (e) {
    let number = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];

    $("#sub-slide-" + number).fadeOut(1200);
    $("#main-slide").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Add e.preventDefault() will avoid to go to top when clicking on a link.
It's pretty the same solution than Ali Sheikhpour gave you.
By this way it's easy to maintain and very understandable (with no repetitions).